# 'Friend WithEvents' in Visual Basic vs. 'private' in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, field

In Windows Forms projects, why does the designer by default use the `Friend WithEvents` attributes in VB.NET and `private` ones in C#?

For example, in a `form.designer.` file:

.cs

```
private Label Label1;
```

.vb

```
Friend WithEvents Label1 as Label;
```

For `WithEvents`, it is more or less clear (for using `Handles`, apparently). But why *Friend* in Visual Basic and *private* in C#?

Comment: I think what's important to know is that modern versions of Visual Studio might change access modifiers from Friend WithEvents to Private WithEvents when editing Forms with the WinForm-Editor thus resulting in compilation errors when the respective controls are being accessed by foreign forms. This is especially a problem when migrating from let's say Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Friend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/friend) is used for compatibility with older Visual Basic code, where normally a control was used outside the form which contained it.
In C# there isn't that necessity.

`private` is a better solution, for new code.

Answer (score 4):

Typically VB.NET leans towards exposing too much (privacy is mostly opt-in) whereas C# is the inverse, privacy is typically opt-out.  As others have mentioned the reason is likely due to VB.NET's legacy and the "friendliness" of exposing everything; it makes it easy to get started but also leads to poor design and additional effort to ensure loose coupling.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is to help with migration from earlier versions of VB as code in the forms tended to be modified from outside more frequently. Friend is also the default.

Private is better from a code design perspective and is used in C# as there is no similar historic coding practice I guess!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Visual Basic is trying to be friendlier to new programmers and allow them to see all the Friend controls in the form from anywhere in their project?

Friend being internal, the only thing I can think of, an I am not sure why the defaults would be different other than to assist new programmers...

Comment: I believe the new programmers should think OOP, and learn its (Black)Box concept.

Comment: OOP is easy to preach, but even with C# many green developers learn just enough to get by and fall into a procedural approach.  Proper OO design requires additional forethought and greater consideration, so naturally it's a skill that develops *after* learning the basics of an OO language.

Comment: I actually offer VB.NET as the better "learning" language; it lets a new developer cut their teeth worrying less about syntax and higher-level design and more about learning the framework. Once a developer is competent with the basic framework tools then they can consider the design and security aspects; it makes for a natural breaking point to make the switch.